# Animation not working when Scrolling

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to animate 10 views in `scrollview`, But the problem is.

Animation start only when `scrollview` stop scrolling.
I want to animate view when scrolling the `scrollview`.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_albumview, null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_temp01);

        view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {

                                System.out.println(">>>>>" + view.getX());
                                if (detectOverLap(view, mainRect)) {
                                    ObjectAnimator objectanimator1, objectanimator2;

                                    objectanimator1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view.findViewById(R.id.imageView), "scaleX", 1.0f);
                                    objectanimator2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view.findViewById(R.id.imageView), "scaleY", 1.0f);
                                    objectanimator1.start();
                                    objectanimator2.start();

                                    System.out.println("ON INNER");
                                }  
                            }
                        });




        return view;
```

this is the views added in scrollview on random location

Thanks
Amit Sharma

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: @ApurvaKolapkar Please check i have updated the code.
Animation is working fine but only when scrolling is stoped but i need when i am scrolling

Comment: Have you found any workaround? I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that helped me out was setting ObjectAnimator's animation duration to zero and setting an Interpolator. So your code should be something like this:

```
System.out.println(">>>>>" + view.getX());
                            if (detectOverLap(view, mainRect)) {
                                ObjectAnimator objectanimator1, objectanimator2;

                                objectanimator1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view.findViewById(R.id.imageView), "scaleX", 1.0f);
                                objectanimator2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view.findViewById(R.id.imageView), "scaleY", 1.0f);
                                objectanimator1.setInterpolator(new FastOutSlowInInterpolator());
                                objectanimator2.setInterpolator(new FastOutSlowInInterpolator());
                                objectanimator1.setDuration(0);
                                objectanimator2.setDuration(0);
                                objectanimator1.start();
                                objectanimator2.start();

                                System.out.println("ON INNER");
                            }
```